# json4s extract error in scala with map values

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I use `json4s native`,with a json string like this

```
val myjson = """
{
    "normative":"C",
    "prefixType":{
        "cod":["smallint", "int", "varchar(5)"],
        "des":["varchar", "string"],
        "fec":["timestamp"],
        "hms":["timestamp"],
        "tim":["timestamp"],
        "imp":["decimal","Float", "Double"]
        },
    "fixcolname":{
        "aud_usuario":"varchar(8)",
        "aud_fec":"timestamp",
        "aud_tim":"timestamp"
        },
    "symSep":"_", 
    "maxLength":26
}"""
```

And a case class

```
case class colVerify(prefixType: Map[String, Array[String]], fixcolname: Map[String, String], symSep: String, maxLength: Int)
```

and I want to extract it from the json String

```
val t = parse(myjson)
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
val myvfy = t.extract[colVerify]
```

then got an error like this

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json4s.package$MappingException: Parsed JSON values do not match with class constructor
args=Map(des -> [Ljava.lang.String;@d7b1517, fec -> [Ljava.lang.String;@16c0663d, tim -> [Ljava.lang.String;@23223dd8, hms -> [Ljava.lang.String;@4ec6a292, imp -> [Ljava.lang.String;@1b40d5f0, cod -> [Ljava.lang.String;@ea4a92b),Map(aud_usuario -> varchar(8), aud_fec -> timestamp, aud_tim -> timestamp),_,26
arg types=scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap,scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map3,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer
constructor=public colVerify(scala.collection.mutable.Map,scala.collection.mutable.Map,java.lang.String,int)
```

Seems like it has problem with the type of Map, but how can I convert it implicitly?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the maps in your case class are mutable maps, is this intentional or did you accidently `import collection.mutable.Map`?

If you *really* want the mutable maps, you could implement a custom Serializer as described here: https://github.com/json4s/json4s#serializing-non-supported-types

My first idea to add another constructor with immutable maps in case class doesn't seem to work reliably.

Comment: I have `import collection.mutable.Map`, and then I found that it's a problem of json4s, that didn't support convert to mutable collection of scala, finally I give up the use of mutable in case class. And it works fine.